# Not able to read xlsb file using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a xlsb file. I am trying to read it using Python. But I am not able to read it. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: I have installed pyxlsb. But i am not able to read the xlsb file.

Comment: Then post a new question detailing the error you find with your attempt, and include your code.